# Apache add subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, subdomain

I need to add a subdomain to [this](http://login.acorn.lt) server, i added this

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName images.login.acorn.lt
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName login.acorn.lt
</VirtualHost>
```

config to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and restarted with `apachectl -k graceful` , without error. But images.login.acorn.lt is down

Comment: Any errors in error.log?

Comment: Might be obvious, but is your images.login.acorn.lt DNS name defined?  I cannot see it, is it only local?

Comment: @Tonin it turns it's not, how can i do that
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a valid DNS record for your subdomain too. You can accomplish this by either setting up an individual DNS entry for each new subdomain, or just creating a wildcard entry for *.domain.com that is a CNAME to domain.com. With the wildcard method, you can put whatever.domain.com in your apache config, and they will all just work without any other configuration. But every namebasedvirtualhost has to have a valid DNS entry. Moreover custom domain name must be allowed on server.For Custom sudomain domain name you have to specify and register proper dns.

Comment: How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You have register your custom sub-domain name with dns registrar to make it it working.